# directive with isolate scope and compilation wipes out mode

Tags: angularjs

I have a directive that consists of a select dropdown, when the select is changed (im watching the modelid) i'm recompiling the template and setting the element to the compiled html. the bizarre thing is, the span shows the correct value where as the select text is incorrect.

what i am trying to do and if anyone can provide a better solution is have part of the template dynamic so when a select is changed, i want a different part loaded in (which would also need compiling as it would have binded fields)

can anyone see why its happening please?
Thx.

```
app.directive('editor', ['$http', '$compile', function ($http, $compile) {

function createTemplate(id) {

    var template =
        '<div><select class="form-control" ng-model="lettingsourceId" >' +
            '<option ng-repeat="lettingsrc in lettingSources" value="{{lettingsrc.id}}">{{lettingsrc.description}}</option>' +
        '</select></div>';

    return template + "<span>" + id + "</span>";
}

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        $scope.values= [{ id: "1", description: 'testa' }, { id: "2", description: 'testb' }];
        $scope.modelid= "1";

        var html = createTemplate($scope.modelid);
        $element.html($compile(html)($scope));

        $scope.$watch('modelid', function () {
            var html = createTemplate($scope.modelid);
            $element.html($compile(html)($scope));
        });
    }
};
```

}]);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

checkout [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ekw4novXCxBfqVFvQVmT?p=preview)

```
app.directive('editor', ['$http', '$compile', function ($http, $compile) {

function createTemplate(id) {

    var template =
        '<div><select class="form-control" ng-model="' + id + '" >' +
            '<option ng-repeat="lettingsrc in lettingSources" value="{{lettingsrc.id}}">{{lettingsrc.description}}</option>' +
        '</select>';

    return template + "<span>{{" + id + "}}</span></div>";
}

return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {},
    link: function ($scope, $element, $attributes) {

        $scope.lettingSources= [{ id: "1", description: 'testa' }, { id: "2", description: 'testb' }];
        $scope.modelid= "1";

        var html = createTemplate('modelid');
        var element = angular.element(html);
        $element.append(element);
        $compile(element)($scope);

        // $scope.$watch('modelid', function () {
        //     var html = createTemplate($scope.modelid);
        //     // $element.html(html);
        //     // $compile(elm)($scope);
        // });
    }
};
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that, bit of a doh moment for me there !